# reason for different location of sun when rising in the morning

Tags: sunrise

Observed from the same geographical location, why does the sun rises from different points on the horizon during different parts of the year?

Thank you.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39670/16685

Comment: I think that the questions of these two threads are different. In mine it is about a location on the horizon at the sunset time, not any angle as in their thread.

Comment: The azimuth and altitude angles give the location of a celestial body relative to the horizon and the meridian (the north-south line). Eg, a body on the horizon that's 80° east of north has an azimuth of 80°. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth

Comment: In other words, you asked for the "location on the horizon". The only way an answer can work for everyone is to give an azimuth or compass bearing. Both are the same as giving an angle in degrees.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is there a tool online to find out the compass bearing of a sunrise for a given location on Earth at a given date? Thank you.

Comment: @JaniikN. [timeanddate.com/sun](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/) is one such site. Enter your location in the text box and then the return key. You can change the month to see the direction change over the course of a year. BTW, this is a duplicate.

Comment: The top answer to the linked question explains not only what happens, but why it happens. It's because the Earth is tilted with respect to its orbit.

Comment: Thank you David for your explanation.